# how to make code print Suspended instead of won

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

Code doesn't output Suspended but outputs Won when the user inputs true. Can someone help explain what have I done wrong with this code, please?

```java
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean isSuspended = read.nextBoolean();
       int ourScore = read.nextInt();
       int theirScore = read.nextInt();
       
       if(isSuspended = true){
             if(ourScore > theirScore){
               System.out.println("Won");
           } if(ourScore < theirScore){
               System.out.println("Lost");
           } if(ourScore == theirScore){
               System.out.println("Draw");
           }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Suspended");
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `=` incorrectly. In your example, `if(isSuspended = true) {}` means:

```java
boolean isSuspended = read.nextBoolean();
//...
isSuspended = true;

if(isSuspended) {} // it will be always true
```

To **not assigned** but **check**, you should use `==` instead.

```java
if (isSuspended == true) {
   // if true
} else {
   // if false
}
```

or better:

```java
if (isSuspended) {
   // if true
} else {
   // if false
}
```

***P.S.** I think you also mixed up the if cases.*

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean suspended = scan.nextBoolean();
    int ourScore = scan.nextInt();
    int theirScore = scan.nextInt();

    if (suspended)
        System.out.println("Suspended");
    else if (ourScore > theirScore)
        System.out.println("Won");
    else if (ourScore < theirScore)
        System.out.println("Lost");
    else
        System.out.println("Draw");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the line:

```java
if(isSuspended = true) {
```

It should be

```java
if(isSuspended == true) {
```

or even:

```java
if(isSuspended) {
```

`isSuspended = true` (with one `=`) assigns a new value to the variable `isSuspended` overriding whatever the user has entered.

In Java, those value assignments are treated like a value: `isSuspended = true` has the value `true` (so everywhere you could place a boolean like `true` or `false`, you can also put an expression like `yourVariableName = true` or `myVariable = false`, which also act like a boolean, but have the "side effect" of assigning a value to the variable).

If you want to compare a value for equality, you need to use `==` (or `.equals(...)` for Strings and other objects). If you want to check if a boolean is `true`, you don't even need `== true`, because the value of that comparison will be `true` or `false` in the end, which is just the value that the boolean you wanted to compare originally had.